# Window function not working on non selected rows

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, window-functions

I'm creating auto switching partitions procedure.
I'm creating table that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #MaxPartitionRows
    (MaxRows BIGINT NOT NULL,
    PNumber INT NOT NULL, 
    PFName SYSNAME NOT NULL,
    Value VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL)
```

I'm using it to decide whether to merge partitions or not.
The columns are: max rows in tables per partition function, partition number, partition function and boundary value.
The logic is to merge partition only if the next partition is also empty.
So I tried this query:

```
 SELECT @vcPartitionFunction    = PFName,
    @vcBoundaryValue        = Value,
    @NextPartitionRowNum    = LEAD(MaxRows) OVER (ORDER BY PNumber)
FROM #MaxPartitionRows
WHERE PNumber = @iMinPartitionNumberToSwitchOut
```

The problem that I've faced is that *@NextPartitionRowNum* gets *NULL* as a value, even if there are rows in the table with bigger partition number.
My guess is that engine don't need to scan next row so it returns *NULL*.
Is that the correct assumption?
In this case the workaround is simple, I just use

```
SELECT @NextPartitionRowNum = MaxRows 
    FROM #MaxPartitionRows
    WHERE PNumber = @iMinPartitionNumberToSwitchOut + 1
```

But what if I couldn't do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LEAD()` is calculated after the `WHERE` clause has limited the result to one row (I'm assuming that `(PNumber)` is unique). That's why you always get `NULL` for `@NextPartitionRowNum`.

You could use your select, only if you are sure that there are no gaps in the `PNumber` values:

```
SELECT @NextPartitionRowNum = MaxRows 
    FROM #MaxPartitionRows
    WHERE PNumber = @iMinPartitionNumberToSwitchOut + 1 ;
```

Alternatively, you could use this (gaps or not, doesn't affect it):

```
SELECT @vcPartitionFunction    = p.PFName,
    @vcBoundaryValue        = p.Value,
    @NextPartitionRowNum    = n.MaxRows
FROM #MaxPartitionRows AS p
  OUTER APPLY
    ( SELECT TOP (1) n.MaxRows
      FROM #MaxPartitionRows AS n
      WHERE n.PNumber > p.PNumber
      ORDER BY n.PNumber
    ) AS n
WHERE p.PNumber = @iMinPartitionNumberToSwitchOut ;
```

If you prefer window functions, this would work, too. First calculate `LEAD()` over the entire table, then restrict with `WHERE`:

```
WITH cte AS
  ( SELECT PFName, Value, PNumber, 
           NextMaxRows = LEAD(MaxRows) OVER (ORDER BY PNumber)
    FROM #MaxPartitionRows
  )
SELECT @vcPartitionFunction    = PFName,
       @vcBoundaryValue        = Value,
       @NextPartitionRowNum    = NextMaxRows
FROM cte
WHERE PNumber = @iMinPartitionNumberToSwitchOut ;
```

Comment: Thanks for an explanation and suggested solution, somehow didn't thought about apply function.